# git merge changes both local and remote branch

Tags: git, github, merge

I have 2 branches local and remote like below.

```
# dev
  master
```

Right now I have merged changes local using git checkout master & git merge dev. It works great. Using git status I got below:

```
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 46 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

But the remote I haven't done anything yet. So how to merge remote branches? Should I just git push origin master? or what?

Comment: yes, you need `git push origin master`

Comment: But before "git checkout máster" you must obtain last commits with "git fetch origin"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to "merge the remote branches" but update their references according to your local changes (merge or whatever else).

Just `git push origin master` to update the remote master with your local merge of dev branch.